# Display 5 records per row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently this just makes a long list. How do I display this with 5 records per row instead of 1?

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>

<p><%= tag_search(tag) %></p>

<% end %>
```

currently

```
tag1
tag2
tag3
tag4
tag5
tag6
tag7
...
```

desired

```
tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5
tag6 tag7
```

I know this is really basic but I just cannot manage to find the right google search terms to get the answer on my own. 
Thanks!

this is what I ended up using

```
<table>
<% @tags.in_groups_of(4, false) do |row_tag| %>
  <tr>
    <% for tag in row_tag %>
      <td><%= tag_search(tag) %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the ActiveSupport method in_groups_of to take an array and put it into groups

```
<% @tags.in_groups_of(5).each do |tag_array| %>
  <% tag_array.each |tag| %>
  ...
```

[Original Doc from Rails Docs](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html)

```
%w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7).in_groups_of(3) {|g| p g}
  ["1", "2", "3"]
  ["4", "5", "6"]
  ["7", nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<% @tags.each_with_index do |tag, index| %>
  <%= tag_search(tag) %>
  <%= "<br />" if (index % 5).zero? %>
<% end %>
```

You can also use ActiveSupport's `in_group_of`.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to do it but this will work:

```
  <% @tags.each do |tag, i| %>
         <%= '<p>' if i == 1 %>
         <%= tag_search(tag) %>
         <% if i == 5 %>
             <% i = 0 %>
             </p>
         <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Please avoid setting variables in the view.

Answer (score 0):

.each should be on the inner loop

Comment: hi Mike - which inner loop? Perhaps you could provide a re-worked example of the code showing the solution that you mean.