# Display an array into multiple columns on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array "$a" and the below code in my view displays all the elements in a single column.
How do I display them into 5 columns?

```
<ul>  
 <% for w in $a %>    
   <%= w %><br/>
 <% end %>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show us the "below code"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question [Display 5 records per row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037668/display-5-records-per-row)

```
 <% @tags.in_groups_of(5).each do |tag_array| %>
      <% tag_array.each |tag| %>
      will output 5 tags here
      <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: <% $a.in_groups_of(5).each do |t1| %>  
  <% t1.each do |t2| %>  
   <%= t2 %>  
  <% end %><br/>  
 <% end %>

Comment: `<% tag_array.each |tag| %>` should be `<% tag_array.each do |tag| %>`.