# Display 4 entry per row with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display videos in rows of 4 entries.

It should look like that (an `x` being a video) :

```
x | x | x | x
x | x | x | x
x | x | x | x
```

Right now, I am calling a `while` loop that will stop when I can fetch 4 more videos (so it won't break the layout by displaying only three on one row). I am using a variable (`n`) to take 4 videos (`@videos[n..n+3]`).

```
- n = 0
  - while n+4 < @videos.count do
    .row
      %ul.thumbnails            
        - @videos[n..n+3].each do |v|
          %li.span3
            # code for showing the video
    - n +=4
```

There *must* be a better way to do that.

**UPDATE**

I found the awesome Rails function [in_groups_of](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html).

As seen in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4037770/1146764)

> The ActiveSupport method in_groups_of takes an array and puts it into groups

**UPDATE 2**

My first update is a working solution, but the accepted answer is better.

Comment: Is it *really* necessary to have the row wrapper element? The server-side code could be way simpler if [inline-block styling](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap's `.thumbnails` component and `.span3` so you're already automatically getting rows of four. You don't need any loops, nested lists or utility methods.

```
%ul.thumbnails            
  - @videos.each do |v|
    %li.span3
      # code for showing the video
```

It just works: http://jsbin.com/uguqib/edit

P.S. ActiveSupport's `in_groups_of` is just a wrapper around Ruby's built-in [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) with added filler items to round out the last set. If you need filler elements like this you can do the padding on your own pretty easily:

```
- @videos += [ nil ] * ( 4 - @videos.size % 4 )
%ul.thumbnails
  - @videos.each do |v|
    %li.span3
      - if v then render_the_video_element
      - else      render_a_filler_element end
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works better than mine with the `in_groups_of` method. I didn't know I had to use twitter bootstrap's thumbnails that way!